# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o - JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I know that this problem has been raised here many times, but i cant figure out the error of my code. I'm getting this error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o'

Here's my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "json-http-server.aspx/GetDoctors",
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: myFunction,
    failure: function (response) {
    alert("AJAX error");
}
});
```

Here's my function that will parse the data returned:

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
    var out = "";
    out += "<table border='1'>";
    out += "<tr><th>Title</th>";
    out += "<th>Name</th>";
    out += "<th>Gender</th>";
    out += "<th>Address</th>";
    out += "<th>Hospital</th></tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr>";
        out += "<td>";
        out += arr[i].Title;
        out += "</td>";
        out += "<td>";
        out += arr[i].Name;
        out += "</td>";
        out += "<td>";
        out += arr[i].Gender;
        out += "</td>";
        out += "<td>";
        out += arr[i].Address;
        out += "</td>";
        out += "<td>";
        out += arr[i].Hospital;
        out += "</td>";
        out += "</tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("OutputDiv").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Here's is my JSON data returned from a webservice:

```
'[{
    "Title":"Univ. Prof. Dr.",
    "Name":"John",
    "Gender":"Doe", 
    "Address":"Washington DC, USA",
    "Hospital":"Washington General Hospital"
  }
  {
    "Title":"Univ. Prof. Dr.",
    "Name":"Billy",
    "Gender":"Joe",
    "Address":"California, USA",
    "Hospital":"AKH Univ-Kl.f.Innere Med. II"
  }
  {
    "Title":"Univ. Prof. Dr.",
    "Name":"Alex",
    "Gender":"Haize",
    "Address":"Michigan, 2500, USA",
    "Hospital":"Rheuma-SKA Baden der SVA der gew. Wirtschaft"
}]'
```

Comment: You don't need to parse the response; jQuery will have already done so before your "success" function is called.

Comment: When you add the `dataType` JSON, jQuery parses it for you. You're parsing it again, this time parsing an object and getting an error

Comment: `data: '',` — An empty string is not valid JSON, you shouldn't tell the server that your request contains JSON if it isn't true. Remove the line: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  var arr = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
> ```

The JSON has already been parsed before `response` was populated.

(jQuery will do this under two circumstances: If you specify `dataType: 'json'` (which you do) or if you don't specify a dataType and the server says that the response is JSON (which it should)).

You are (implicitly) converting it to a string (`"[object Object]"`) and trying to parse *that* as JSON (which it isn't).

Remove that line.

Comment: I removed that line and replaced with "response.d", the error has gone but it display in all columns "undefined".

Comment: @raurau — Since there is no `d` property anywhere in your JSON, that isn't surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data is invalid, you're missing commas (`,`) between `}` and `{`.

Fixed:

```
'[{
    "Title":"Univ. Prof. Dr.",
    "Name":"John",
    "Gender":"Doe", 
    "Address":"Washington DC, USA",
    "Hospital":"Washington General Hospital"
  },
  {
    "Title":"Univ. Prof. Dr.",
    "Name":"Billy",
    "Gender":"Joe",
    "Address":"California, USA",
    "Hospital":"AKH Univ-Kl.f.Innere Med. II"
  },
  {
    "Title":"Univ. Prof. Dr.",
    "Name":"Alex",
    "Gender":"Haize",
    "Address":"Michigan, 2500, USA",
    "Hospital":"Rheuma-SKA Baden der SVA der gew. Wirtschaft"
}]'
```

Comment: It does not display the output @Siguza.